# how to get running processes

Tags: linux, process, ps

I'm trying to get running processes from a linux server but I having some doubts. If I get top exit I have:

```
# top -b -n1 | head -n5
top - 16:18:19 up 60 days, 21:22,  8 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.13, 0.15
Tasks: 1274 total,   7 running, 1267 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.6% us,  2.4% sy,  0.0% ni, 95.8% id,  0.1% wa,  0.0% hi,  0.0% si
Mem:   6291556k total,  5269044k used,  1022512k free,    29976k buffers
Swap:  6291448k total,    82508k used,  6208940k free,   649292k cached
```

What I want to know is which processed are the "7" that top says that are "running" in the second line.

I've try "ps axo stat,euid,ruid,tty,tpgid,sess,pgrp,ppid,pid,pcpu,comm" and filter by "stat" status equal to "R" but I'm not able to get this 4 processes. I've always get the "ps and grep" and sometimes I get another one, but not not the seven tha ttop shows.

Is there any way to obtain that?

Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typed *man top* and read about *top -i* which displays non-idle, non-zombie processes.